# Android Layout issue in different screens size

Tags: android, android-layout

I make a layout with this layout XML:
and i have a problem that in every screen (2.7in, 3.2in ,3.7in,4in .....) the 3 TextView are locate in a different position in the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/profile2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/uph" 
        android:layout_gravity="top|center" android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="315dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str_phone2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:onClick="onClick2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:onClick="onClick1"
            android:text="@string/str_phone"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:onClick="onClickEmail"
        android:text="@string/str_email"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_marginTop="19dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? If you can show us what you want the layout to look like, we may be able to see what the issue is.

Comment: which is the root layout ?? please Edit your question ..

Comment: I want to have a layout with background image as i define, and 3 textview, the first and the second need to be horizontal each other and the third below them

Comment: don't give Fix size to controls..

Comment: i had past code below try this, if find any problem then tell me..

Comment: i found a problem with another screens, can i define a diffrent layout for each screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code i had modify it as per your requirment..ans set images then see.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_gravity="top|center" 
        />

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"     
     android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text1"                 
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
            android:onClick="onClick2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:onClick="onClick1"
            android:text="hello"

            android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:onClick="onClickEmail"
        android:text="Hello"    

        android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_marginTop="19dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you only need one Root layout, so please remove the second xmlns:android definition.

Second, to display views next to each other, use a LinearLayout which is set to horizonatl. Then set your views to be `layout_weight="1"` and `layout_width="fill_parent"`. This will make sure your TextViews are next to each other.

Then inside your root layout, just place the third TextView under the LinearLayout I just described.